# JavaScript click event only fires the first time on InfoPath form

Tags: javascript, jquery, infopath2010

I am trying to get a button to display an alert every time the button is clicked. Currently, it only fires the first time I click, and I have to refresh the page to make it work again. Because this is a Submit and New button, I need it to be able to keep the form values which would be lost if it reloaded. The alert is used to provide feedback to the user. This is my code:

```
$('input[value="Submit and New"]').on('click', function(){
alert('The request form has been submitted successfully. To submit a new form for the same user, change the form values and click on either the "Submit" or "Submit and New" button');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set click using document and it should work fine

```
   $(document).on('click','input[value="Submit and New"]', function(){
    alert('The request form has been submitted successfully. To submit a new form for the same user, change the form values and click on either the "Submit" or "Submit and New" button');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4QWu/

Answer (score 0):

you are probably calling the function before document is loaded, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[value="Submit and New"]').on('click', function(){
alert('The request form has been submitted successfully. To submit a new form for the same user, change the form values and click on either the "Submit" or "Submit and New" button');
    }
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/fRrTC/)